# Using R or Matplotlib (Python), how can I create a venn diagram based on value comparisons for each row of a CSV file?

Tags: python, r, csv, matplotlib, venn-diagram

I got a project which required making venn diagrams, and I am starting to learn python (using 2.7) so I figured trying to learn R as well would overload me with work. So, I learned online about matplotlib. Basically, what I need to do is create a venn diagram which compares the value under every column to generate a venn diagram. So if my csv had the following data:

```
Month    x    y
Sept    -1    1
Oct    0    1
Nov    1    1
Dec    -1    -1
```

The overlap would show a value of 2 (because nov and dec have the same value), the x circle by itself would show a value of 1, from sept (the 0 needs to be ignored), and the y circle would show a value of 2, from sept and oct.

I think this is a pretty complicated program, but I have no idea where to start, other than just starting with:

```
from matplotlib_venn import venn2
```

When I use an online tool such as [Venny](http://bioinfogp.cnb.csic.es/tools/venny/), it just finds the numbers that are similar between the lists instead of doing a row-by-row comparison. This results in nothing in values of 0 in the outer circles, and the number 3 in the overlap (because there are three different values in the input: -1, 0, and 1.

Alternatively, if this would instead be very easy using R instead of Python, could you help me with that?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In R there are many options to build venn diagram. You can get some of them

```
library(sos)
findFn('Venn diagramm')
```

For example using  `VennDiagram` (the first in the list) you can get this graph. I used random values to generate it since it is not very clear how do you consider shared and intersection regions in your question.

[image]

```
library(VennDiagram)
# You should replace the random values here by your set of values
## 
set.seed(1)
A <- sample(1:100, 25, replace = FALSE)
B <- sample(1:100, 25, replace = FALSE)
C <- sample(1:100, 25, replace = FALSE)
D <- sample(1:100, 25, replace = FALSE)

venn.plot <- venn.diagram(
    x = list(
        Sept = A,
        Oct = D,
        Nov = B,
        Dec = C
    ),
    filename = NULL,
    col = "transparent",
    fill = c("cornflowerblue", "green", "yellow", "darkorchid1"),
    alpha = 0.50,
    label.col = c("orange", "white", "darkorchid4", "white", 
                                "white", "white", "white", "white", "darkblue", "white", 
                                "white", "white", "white", "darkgreen", "white"),
    cex = 1.5,
    fontfamily = "serif",
    fontface = "bold",
    cat.col = c("darkblue", "darkgreen", "orange", "darkorchid4"),
    cat.cex = 1.5,
    cat.pos = 0,
    cat.dist = 0.07,
    cat.fontfamily = "serif",
    rotation.degree = 270,
    margin = 0.2
)

grid.draw(venn.plot)
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! But actually, I want the circles to be x and y, so the overlap would be the a count of how many rows the values are the same. The month is actually extraneous information, sorry for not clarifying that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand your numbers but the `matplotlib-venn` package is pretty easy to use. In your example with `(Xy, Yx, XY) = (1, 2, 2)` from your text, you would just run

```
import matplotlib_venn as venn
v = venn.venn2((1, 2, 2))
v.get_label_by_id('A').set_text('x')
v.get_label_by_id('B').set_text('y')
```

The docs are [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib-venn) and it's reasonably straightforward. The trickier bit will be extracting the `(Xy, Yx, XY)` tuple from the data but I don't really understand your calculation, sorry. If you can explain it a bit more, perhaps I can offer some more advice there.